# How to maintain the character after converting from dataframe to array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a dataframe of pandas whose Page field has entries like:   `Francisco_el_matemático_(serie_de_televisión_de_2017)_es.wikipedia.org_all-access_spider`

I use the `.values` to convert it to **numpy** array, but it appears to be   `Francisco_el_matem\xc3\xa1tico_(serie_de_televisi\xc3\xb3n_de_2017)_es.wikipedia.org_all-access_spider`

Is there anyway, to keep the original format of the string?

Comment: Are you using Python 2?

Comment: Yes. 2.7 version

Comment: Seems to be working for me. Please add a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

It's actually encoding problem.

Add this line  at the beginning of your python script

```
 # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```